# How to copy the logging information of a program to an existing file?

Tags: python, macos, logging, python-3.6

My book states that to copy the logging information to a file ( assume it's name is `cover.txt` ) add the following code in your program: `logging.basicConfig(filename='cover.txt',level=logging.DEBUG,format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')`

When I run the program, a new file named `cover` is created in the documents folder! And the logging information is copied to that file and not to the file that I have made.

Does this always happen? If not, how can I copy the logging info to my original file `cover.txt`?

Comment: you ask to create `cover.txt` ,that seems to work ? Maybe the extensions  are hidden, check your folder parameters, or try with  `filename='cover.log'`

Comment: @PRMoureu `cover.log` creates another file different from my file and the file that the program itself first created :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the program, a new file named cover is created in the
>   documents folder! And the logging information is copied to that file
>   and not to the file that I have made.

The program is working correctly. You don't create the logging file first, the application will create it automatically.

This is because the logging module in Python is very comprehensive, it can log to files, network locations, the console, email addresses, other servers and when it comes to logging to files - it can automatically rotate the log files.

For example, you can configure the logging module to create a new log file every day, or after the log file reaches a certain size, create a new log file.

That's why the program is creating files for you.

If the file is called `cover` this is because by default Windows will hide extensions of files.

You can disable this option from the "View" menu of Windows Explorer.